# Not able to type inside ISeries using Pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Am able to open IBM ISeries using Pywinauto but am not able to write(TypeKeys) eg.123 inside that screen.
Rather am able to

```
dlg_evolve.TypeKeys("{TAB}")-- cursor moves to next tab
dlg_evolve.TypeKeys("{HOME}")-- cursor moves to home
dlg_evolve.TypeKeys("123")-- not typing :(
```

Comment: You need to type keys into the control, not the whole dialog. Probably `{TAB}` is switching the keyboard focus from edit box to inappropriate control.

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. Post the output of `print_control_identifiers()`, maybe the screenshot, which control should receive the keys etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . The following are the control identifiers of the application , for dlg_evolve.print_control_identifiers() .With the help of Swapy the correct identifier is "Port:PCSWS:Pres:00400000" .So we tried to enter the keystrokes through ,dlg_evolve.PortPCSWSPres00400000.TypeKeys("ABCD") .But we couldn't succeed .

Comment: I am able to enter from Keyboard . Does it mean that inputs other than from Keyboard is disabled ? If so ,why I am able to navigate across using HOME or TAB .Any suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvriq.png

Comment: What is the output of `dlg_evolve.PortPCSWSPres00400000.children()`? or `dlg_evolve.PortPCSWSPres00400000.descendants()`? Are there some edit box wrapper? Target edit box might be a child of this "blah-blah-blah" control with almost the same rectangle. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Please check the below image for the response.https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRu5m.png

Comment: Which pywinauto version do you use? It seems 0.5.4 or before. I'd recommend to update it to 0.6.0. Or even to master branch by `pip install https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/master.zip` (it's close to 0.6.1 that is planned this week).

Comment: python setup.py install -- Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools-scm/: timed out -- S
ome packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools-scm' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages ma
y not be found!
No local packages or download links found for setuptools-scm

Comment: Please try `pip install setuptools-scm` first (it should work this way, I checked). Will remove this dependency in 0.6.1.

Comment: is there any llink to download setup files. it shows me connection timeout issue

Comment: Probably PyPI is not available on your machine (isolated lab network?). Manual installation steps are here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#manual-installation

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thanks for your Reply, you are right we are in separate lab network. i have downloaded the pywinauto 0.6.0 and once trying to install it throws me the same error :"Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools-scm/: timed out -- S
ome packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools-scm' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages ma
y not be found!
No local packages or download links found for setuptools-scm." Hope so u ll provide 0.6.1 soon which will not depend on PyPI.

Comment: Can you download https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto/archive/setup_fixes.zip, unpack and try `python setup.py install`?

Comment: Thanks @VasilyRyabov i have installed it and got successfully installed.Should i change import pywinauto to other..?

Comment: When i try to find existing open wondows using below code:'import pywinauto
import time
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
handles = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows()
for w_handle in handles:
    wind = app.window_(handle=w_handle)
    print wind.Texts() : '  the error gets displayed Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openwind.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pywinauto
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 37, in <module
>
ImportError: No module named six

Comment: Yes, because you need to install modules `pyWin32`, `comtypes` and `six` as described in Manual Installation instruction (see the links in the docs). These dependencies are required in any case.

Comment: Thx fr help we have installed all 3 modules .But the earlier below mentioned code which was working fine was not working now. Code:import pywinauto
import time
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
handles = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows()
for w_handle in handles:
    wind = app.window_(handle=w_handle)
    #print wind.Texts()  .............It throws the error wind =app.window_(handle=w_handle)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 1126, in window pywinauto.application.AppNotConnected: Please use start or connect before trying anything else

Comment: Obviously you forgot to call `app.start(...)` or `app.connect(...)`. The error message is clear: `AppNotConnected: Please use start or connect before trying anything else`

Comment: Hi Vasily, this is my simple program 'from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.Start_("Notepad.exe")' .. but it showserror Traceback (most recent call last):File "notepad.py", line 3, in <module>app.Start_("Notepad.exe") File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 1153, in __get
attribute__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 1139, in __get
item__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 1126, in window pywinauto.application.AppNotConnected: Please use start or connect before trying

Comment: `Start_` is removed since 0.6.0. Please use `.start("notepad.exe")`

Comment: Thanks Vasily , i wanted to list out the existing opened windoes below are my code ''import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
handles = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows()
for w_handle in handles:
   wind = app.window_(handle=w_handle)
   print wind.Texts()' while execution it throws me error "  File "8.py", line 8, in <module>
    wind = app.window_(handle=w_handle)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 1126, in windo
w
pywinauto.application.AppNotConnected: Please use start or connect before trying
 anything else"

Comment: OK, first I'd recommend you more practice with Python as a programming language. pywinauto may look very easy first time, but desktop GUI automation is really very complicated area. Some programming skills would be very helpful. If calling start() or connect() method is a problem, more complicated algorithms don't make sense. Sorry, many people on StackOverflow would expect some effort from you as well. It's impossible to guide every simple step. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) is a good starting point. It explains many basic issues.